# Stop multiple Dialog windows being opened

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a ajax call for the partialview of my webpage, then pull title and data from it before putting it in a Dialog window. However when I create the dialog, it opens once correctly and 6 more times as an empty Dialog - just the title bar.

In chrome I can see the partialView contains the HTMLDivElement, and 7 HTMLScriptElements so that accounts for the multiple opens - however if I open the Dialog for just that div element it will not load the scripts (and thus lookups and tabs do not work).

```
  $.ajax(url)
  .success(function (partialViewHtml) {
     // get page data

     $(partialViewHtml).dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        height: sheight,
        width: swidth
     });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been banging my head on a wall for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to have understood, this is normal because of the 7 elements in the jQuery collection on which you open the dialog.

You should add the script elements separately to the page, using for example

```
$('body').append(scriptElementHTML);
```

And then open your dialog on just the div :

```
$(divHtml).dialog({
```

Comment: Yep this worked. I appended the scripts to the dialog after loading it (Thanks!):
         $(partialViewWindow).dialog({
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            height: sheight,
            width: swidth
         })
         .append(partialScripts);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whthere jQuery ui has a method to close all dialogs, but we can do it like this

```
function createDailog () {
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");  // close all dialogs

    $("<div>fdfdsfdsfdsfds<div>").dialog({
        title: "title",
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        height: 200,
        width: 200
    });
}
```

or you can put a condition like this

```
if(!$(".ui-dialog-content:visible").length){
    // show dialog
}
```